# Microsoft Visual Studio: System.IO.FileNotFoundException in Console App that references Library that should have the File in question

Tags: c#, visual-studio, reference, filenotfoundexception

I created a c# Library class (called IfcManagerLib) in Visual Studio and installed some packages (only on the library) via the NuGet Packages Manager. Now I want to use this library through a Console App (called IfcManagerConsole), so I created one in the same solution, added a reference to IfcManagerLib and added "using IfcManagerLib;" on the top of the console class.
However, if I start the console it always breaks at the moment it tries to execute something from the library class. It outputs the following error:

> System.IO.FileNotFoundException   HResult=0x80070002   Message=Die
>   Datei oder Assembly "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Abstractions,
>   Version=2.2.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60"
>   oder eine Abhängigkeit davon wurde nicht gefunden. Das System kann die
>   angegebene Datei nicht finden.   Source=IfcFileManagerLib
>   StackTrace:    at IfcFileManagerLib.IfcManager.Start() in
>   C:\Users\David\Dropbox\Visual
>   Studio\source\repos\IfcFileManager\IfcFileManagerLib\IfcManager.cs:line
>   101    at IfcFileManagerConsole.Program.Main(String[] args) in
>   C:\Users\David\source\repos\IfcFileManager\IfcFileManagerConsole\Program.cs:line
>   36
>
> Inner Exception 1: FileNotFoundException: Die Datei oder Assembly
>   "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Abstractions, Version=2.1.1.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60" oder eine
>   Abhängigkeit davon wurde nicht gefunden. Das System kann die
>   angegebene Datei nicht finden.

(Sorry, some of it is in German, but I think you mostly know what it is supposed to say)

What really bothers me, is that the path to the IfcManagerLib (C:\Users\David\Dropbox\Visual
Studio\source\repos\IfcFileManager\IfcFileManagerLib\IfcManager.cs) in the above error message is not correct. It is an old path. I rebuilt the solution, unistalled and reinstalled all packages, but the error still exists. Also: "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Abstractions, Version=2.1.1.0" is not correct, I updated it to 2.2.0.0.

Am I correct in the asumption that the console project does NOT need to have the packages installed that the library uses? If yes, what did I do wrong?

EDIT: Okay. Cleaning and rebuilding the solution did a lot already. However, there is one dll called Xbim Geometry that the Console still cannot find. Here is the error message:

> System.IO.FileLoadException   HResult=0x80131621   Message=Failed to
>   load Xbim.Geometry.Engine64.dll   Source=Xbim.Geometry.Engine.Interop 
>   StackTrace:    at
>   Xbim.Geometry.Engine.Interop.XbimGeometryEngine..ctor(ILogger`1
>   logger) in
>   C:\buildagent_os_work\1\s\Xbim.Geometry.Engine.Interop\XbimGeometryEngine.cs:line
>   65    at Xbim.ModelGeometry.Scene.Xbim3DModelContext.get_Engine() in
>   C:\buildagent_os_work\1\s\Xbim.ModelGeometry.Scene\Xbim3DModelContext.cs:line
>   486    at
>   Xbim.ModelGeometry.Scene.Xbim3DModelContext.CreateContext(ReportProgressDelegate
>   progDelegate, Boolean adjustWcs) in
>   C:\buildagent_os_work\1\s\Xbim.ModelGeometry.Scene\Xbim3DModelContext.cs:line
>   678    at IfcFileManagerLib.IfcManager.Start() in
>   C:\Users\david\source\repos\IfcFileManager\IfcFileManagerLib\IfcManager.cs:line
>   82    at IfcFileManagerConsole.Program.Main(String[] args) in
>   C:\Users\david\source\repos\IfcFileManager\IfcFileManagerConsole\Program.cs:line
>   36
>
> Inner Exception 1: FileNotFoundException: Die Datei oder Assembly
>   "Xbim.Geometry.Engine.dll" oder eine Abhängigkeit davon wurde nicht
>   gefunden. Das System kann die angegebene Datei nicht finden.

What I find odd is that unlike the other dlls that I installed on the library project through NuGet manager, the XbimGeometry dll is located in two folders named x64 and x86 where there is a 64-bit and a 32-bit version. Could that be the problem?

Comment: Are both the class library and the console app in the same solution? If yes, did you add the reference as project reference?

Comment: @KlausGütter Yes, they are in the same solution and yes, I added it as a project reference.

Comment: In the properties of the reference, "Copy Local" should be set to true. Can you please check?

Comment: I personaly don't like to build a project in dropbox or in different folders from the solution. Its probably not the problem you are having though I would recommend to change that. If nothing recommended here works you can always compile your first project and reference a DLL from that. That should do the trick... Try the clean/ rebuild + copy local first anyway...

Comment: @KimLage Yes! This fixed it, thank you! I thought it wouldn't be a good idea to have my solution on dropbox, which is why I wanted to move it.
However there is still one specific dll that the console cannot find, but is in the folder of the library. It is a package called Xbim Geometry that I installed through the NuGet Manager. What I find odd is that unlike the other dlls the XbimGeometry package creates two folders (x64 and x86). Can that be the problem?
I will add the error message to the main question.

Comment: Good to know you could fix it. That DLL probably is x64, I think thats why you have different folders... Make sure the reference is marked to copy locally in the solution. Can you go to the reference properties and show us the path is referencing? usually the path is from the root folder (\references) of the solution. Its possible to change the reference paths from the config files in that folder...

Comment: @KimLage Copy Local is set to true and the path to the library project is: C:\Users\David\source\repos\IFCFileManager\IfcFileManagerLib\bin\x64\Release\IfcFileManagerLib.dll
I also forgot to mention: In the library project the Xbim.Geometry.Engine64.dll and Xbim.Geometry.Engine32.dll are listed under the classes I created and not inside References (they have white computers with a blue arrow in the corner as icons). I tried to add them manually as references, but that didn't fix it.

Comment: @KimLage When I look at the properties of the Xbim.Geometry.Engine64.dll it says under Full Path: C:\Users\David\source\repos\IFCFileManager\packages\Xbim.Geometry.Engine.Interop.5.0.163\build\net47\Xbim.Geometry.Engine64.dll. However, that file does not exist under that path. It is under C:\Users\David\source\repos\IfcFileManager\IfcFileManagerLib\bin\x64\Release\x64\Xbim.Geometry.Engine64.dll.
That's how the package got installed. I also tried to copy the dll over to the first path, but again that didn't fix it.

Comment: @KimLage (Sorry for spamming answers) Under "Copy to Output Directory" in the properties of Xbim.Geometry.Engine64.dll it says "Do not copy" and when I try to change it to "Copy always" it says: "Property value not valid. The item 'Xbim.Geometry.Engine64.dll' cannot be mutated."

Comment: It seams that library is not installed in the solution. What I would do:
1. Unistall the library from nugget.
2. Remove the reference you have in the project.
3. Manually copy the dll under the \reference FOLDER of your SOLUTION
4. Add manualy the reference to that DLL.

if that doest work, you'll have to manually install it with the nugget executable. That should install it under the solution folder. What seams to be happening is that your project is referencing the wrong folder..

Comment: Let me know if it helped you, so I can include it as the anwser...

Comment: @KimLage Unfortunately I cannot uninstall the library with Nuget, since several libraries depend on it. Also I saw that the dlls do exists, I confused two folders... However, I found a post on the GitHub page of the team developing the package, where someone had the same issue. The dev wrote: "Geometry engine native code is loaded in runtime so deployment might not recognize it as a dependency. You need to make sure your deployment workflow will pick these dlls up for publishing." I however don't understand what he means by that. Any idea?

Comment: It seams that the dll is loaded after the compiling of the program (runtime = program already running). That said the project will not recognize the reference. Just remove it. What you will need is to include the DLL file manually when deploying or the code that load it will not find it... If you find the piece of code that loads the DLL you'll probably also find the path that the code is expecting it to be...make this test, just try to run it... when you get the error paste the dll to the path it references and try running again... I hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

1. Can you do a clean solution and rebuild the solution.
2. Can you set the reference as Project reference and set "Copy Local" for that reference?